# Embedded databases vs standalone

Tags: database, embedded-database

I have not found the comparison of the two in here. Please give me link if the thread already exists in comment and I will close the thread.

What I am interested is the performance comparison. Are there any significant differences between the two types. I've heard people managed to store millions of records in embedded with no issues. For instance with H2. In life I've never encountered embedded until saw Spring sample books and testing of other stuff with help of embedded databases(easier to set-up and begin mocking an app). How reliable are they? How resources efficient? The context is not about a system with billion users, but about more realistic with couple hundred/thousand users?

You can guess where I am leading, embedded - easier to set up, easier to use - then why bother? I am no DBA to judge other qualities.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you think is the distinction? How do you define "standalone"? Do you mean a server process running on the same machine as your app? I wonder if you haven't found a comparison because you're making an artificial distinction that other people don't use.

Comment: H2 can be run as separate instance on separate machine? The question was written a year ago so I don't recall my original intentions. But what I am still interested is why H2 is not used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Found interesting link, but still awaiting for other opinions.
It seems that H2 IS faster than MySQL and PostgreSQL - http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html , while consuming slightly more memory, which is not true if you look at the assumptions below. (tested on a single computer though)